# Combine multiple .csv files with python from different directory paths

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine multiple .csv files into one .csv file using the dataframe in pandas. the tricky part about this is, i need to grab multiple files from multiple days. Please let me know if this does not make sense. As it currently stands i cannot figure out how to loop through the directory. Could you offer some assistance?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import glob, os


startDate = 20160613
endDate = 20160614

dateRange = endDate - startDate
dateRange = dateRange + 1
todaysDateFilePath = startDate


for x in xrange(dateRange):
    print startDate
    startDate = startDate + 1
    filePath = os.path.join(r"\\export\path", startDate, "preprocessed")
    os.chdir(filePath)
    interesting_files = glob.glob("trade" + "*.csv")

print interesting_files

df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
    full_df = pd.concat(df_list)




saveFilepath = r"U:\Chris\Test_Daily_Fails"
fileList = []


full_df.to_csv(saveFilepath + '\\Files_For_IN' + "_0613_" + ".csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can create `list` `all_files` and in loop append output from `glob` to `all_files`:

```
all_files = []
for x in xrange(dateRange):
    print startDate
    startDate = startDate + 1
    filePath = os.path.join(r"\\export\path", startDate, "preprocessed")
    os.chdir(filePath)
    all_files = all_files + glob.glob("trade" + "*.csv")

print interesting_files
```

Also you need first append all values to `df_list` and then only once `concat` (I indented code for `concat`):

```
df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Sorry, without your file structure it is very hard answering. Maybe help if your `file structure` with sample data `zip` and share.